# Old Meta questions about policies we have since changed

Tags: discussion, site-policy, meta

Should we downvote answers to old questions since they no longer support current policy, so that new users searching for answers don't find these posts and get led astray?

Example(s):

https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/210/18427

<sub>Feel free to add other examples</sub>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one outdated question that has already been historical-locked:

https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/obsolete-iterative-code-reviews-how-can-they-happen-successfully

I can do this with the remaining relevant questions, so that visitors will be redirected to the post with the current site policy.  If you come across one that should be locked as such, feel free to flag it so that a mod can attend to it.